# Curvature in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, curvature

Apparently, the curvature of the image contour of the unit circle $|z| = 1$ under the conformal mapping $w = f(z)$ is
$$\frac{1}{|zf'(z)|} \text{Re}\bigg(1 + \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)}\bigg).$$
How does one show this? How do we even define curvature in complex analysis? I could not find a single book that explains what curvature is in complex analysis.

Comment: Curvature here in defined for a plane curve in the usual sense, having nothing to do with complex analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sky said, the relevant concept of curvature is not something specific to complex analysis. It's the [curvature of plane curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_plane_curves), defined as the rate of change of the unit tangent vector. In complex terms, the argument if the tangent vector at $f(z)$ is $\operatorname{Im} \log (iz f'(z))$.

Let $g(z)=\log (iz f'(z))$. Since
$$g'(z) = \frac1z +\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}$$
the rate of change of $g$ as $z$ moves along the unit circle with unit speed is $iz g'(z) $. (Here $iz$ is the unit  tangent vector for the circle.) Taking imaginary part yields 
$$
\operatorname{Im}\left(i+ \frac{iz f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right)=
\operatorname{Re}\left(1+ \frac{z f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right)
$$
And this needs to be divided by $|f'(z)|$ because when $z$ travels around the unit circle with unit speed, $f(z)$ traverses the image with speed $|f'(z)|$.   The final answer is 
$$
\frac{1}{|f'(z)|}\operatorname{Re}\left(1+ \frac{z f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right)
$$
which is equivalent to yours since $|z|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an extension of the concept of curvature to complex functions that goes beyond this in Tristan Needham's book Visual Complex Analysis.